# Restricted Mean Survival Time vs Hazard Ratio - How to describe the differences?

Tags: survival, cox-model, weighted-mean

I came across [this article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1740774519871447) which discusses some modifications to a traditional clinical trial monitoring setting where a time-to-event outcome is described in terms of the restricted mean survival time (RMST). RMST is the area under the Kaplan Meier survival curve. The difference summarizes the association between group assignment and survival.

The premise of the article is somewhat flawed. They suggest that the HR is *not intperpretable* when the hazards cross (or as a more extreme case when the survival curves cross). It is interpretable, but that is not the sole reason we choose a statistic.

It seems like we should be able to say something about the direction and magnitude of the HR vs the RMST. For instance, when hazards are proportional, I think we could say that $\log (HR )< 0 \Leftrightarrow RMST < 0$ and *vice versa*... but I have no proof. Further, if the hazards are *not* proportional, then the hazard ratio is a time varying quantity. If you fit a Cox model with these data, the HR is a weighted average of the failure-time-specific hazard ratios. I suspect this quantity "favors" earlier survival times, and the RMST difference favors later survival times.

Suppose we standardized associations in terms of $Z$ statistics. Suppose that a trial's survival times are characterized by a hazard ratio of 1 for the first half of the study and a hazard ratio of 2 at the second half of the study. I'd expect to be able to say $Z_{RMST} < Z_{Cox} < 0$. So we'd prefer RMST difference because it has greater power to detect the later association.

[image]

Is there any reference or simple proof to describe the expected findings if we know the general shape of the survival curves?

Comment: I also came across some articles on this subject recently. I think the interpretation part (or lack there of) is better explained in this article: https://dl.uswr.ac.ir/bitstream/Hannan/52654/1/2019%20EHJ%20Volume%2040%20Issue%2017%20May%20%286%29.pdf

Plus us gives some heuristic arguments for effect sizes of HR vs RMST.